# How long do I need to wait before painting an interior PT plywood floor?

Tags: flooring

I recently had my basement floor replaced due to termite infestation.  The floor is concrete and the floor joists are made of pressure treated wood.  The contractor removed the carpeting and pressed wood and replaced it with pressure treated plywood.  The plywood was laid down 6 weeks ago.  I have been running a fan, heater and dehumidifier in my daylight basement and opening windows.    I would like to paint the floor as soon as possible as I am concerned about the harmful effects of the pressure treatment but have received varied answers as to how long I must wait.  Some say 2 weeks, and some say 6 months.  Please advise.

Comment: I hope you're not running the dehumidifier and heater with the windows open. Both are good things, and the fan helps each, but **at the same time** they are not helping each other.

Comment: Water remediation companies used moisture probes to determine the moisture content of wood elements. Perhaps you could get one to test the plywood. You might have to drill holes into the spaces between joist joists or into selected joists to test the content of the interior of the joists.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations vary because conditions vary. Here are the primary factors:

- Initial lumber moisture content
- Concrete moisture content (ongoing; dependent on ground conditions and the presence or absence of vapor barriers below)
- Indoor temperature and humidity level
- Effectiveness of drying mechanisms (dehumidifier, fans, etc.)

The point is that no one can give you a number. You'll have to either rely on look and feel assessment or use sensor hardware to measure moisture content. Also, follow the paint manufacturer's instructions. Some coatings are more tolerant of substrate moisture than others.

Comment: "Also, follow the paint manufacturer's instructions." - that was my first thought, this question should really be directed at the paint manufacturer or the paint store where you're buying it.